# Huge difference in Advanced segment and Custom Report

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, session-scope

Why is the advanced segment and custom report in the below scenario not matching. Need your valuable suggestions from you all.

I have created a custom report to get sessions. I have done this by using the below query

Dimension as Device category

Metrics sessions

filters as page matches regex /products/phone/xperia-z

iam getting figues as mobile(sessions) =  **869,908**

However when i use a advanced segment on Audience-->Mobile--> overview. The query used in the advanced segment is

condition
Filter session using page matchesregex /products/phone/xperia-z

mobile(session) = **1,187,560**

Could you please let us know why there is such a huge difference in custom report and advanced segment, though iam only interested in sessions

Answer (score 1):

Comparing segments with custom reports is not a correct way of populating data. Whenever you apply a segment, it gives data for all the sessions in which your specified page was visited. Whereas in Custom Report, the filter works like a secondary dimension i.e. number of sessions from Mobile in which users directly landed on your page.

Try and using secondary dimension in Audience > Mobile report and your data will match.

// Hiren :P